# Understanding the front controller with PHP

Tags: php, url-routing, front-controller

I'm very new with PHP, and I've managed to create a *really* rough CMS. At the moment, it's using many different pages and includes.

However, if possible I'd like to use a controller rather than having *lots* of pages (I've already got `article.php/admin.php`).

As an example, I'm trying to convert to something like this:

```
switch ( 'admin' ) {
case 'home':
    include 'view/home.php';
    break;

case 'admin':
    include 'view/admin.php';
    break;

case 'article':
    include 'view/article.php';
    break;

default:
    echo 'default';
    break;
}
```

This would be used with `$_GET['page']`, so the admin URL looks like: `http://cms.dev/?page=admin`

However, what happens if I need to go to a subdirectory of admin? For example, if these were hardcoded pages, I would go `admin/new-post.php`. Is there an equivalent I could get, using the `$_GET method`?

Sorry if this has not been explained well. Let me know and I will try and edit it. I've used a smorgsaboard of tutorials so I'm not 100% on any of this.

Comment: When you want to use front controller. Everything should be called from the front controller, not navigate to somewhere else.

Comment: Check this tutorial [link](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html)`mvc`.

Comment: This is more fitting of a router, not a controller.  But this code will always include view/admin.php because you are switching on a string not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can have forward slashes in your `$_GET['page']` variable, so `https://cms.dev/?page=admin/new-post.php` should work fine.

Alternatively you can put this into your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

And then get it from the REQUEST_URI:

```
$uri = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);
```